# rename or change the about-magento-demo-store URL breaks on the left side bar

Tags: magento-1.9

I changed the URL key for "about-magento-demo-store" to be simply "about-us". I figured out that I then needed to edit the "footer_links_company" so that the appropriate <li> looked like this...
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}about-us/">About Us</a></li>
About the time I thought how clever I was I noticed that while that works fine if I click on the "About Us" I get that page to pull just fine EXCEPT I see on that page there's a new menu area on the left hand column. If I click on that "About Us" I get a 404 error.
Where is the file that is still referencing the original "about-magento-demo-store" URL?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log into your Magento's backend.
Open `CMS` -> `Static Blocks` and edit the block with identifier `cms_menu`. There you'll find your link-list to update.

Comment: ahhh, there it is! I just couldn't lay my eyes on where that one was. Thanks much.